# Populating new date in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am struggling with how to populate a new date in javascript.

```
var startDate = new Date();
var endDate = new Date();
```

In my html page I thought to use selects:

```
<form>Start date:
      <div data-inline="true">

        <select name="day" id="day">
          <option value="01">1</option>
          <option value="02">2</option>
          <option value="03">3</option>
        </select>
```

etc etc

in my javascript I have

```
var startDate = new Date();
startDate.setTime(month + " " + day + " , " + year + " " + hours +:+ minute +:+ second); 

var endDate = new Date();
endDate.setTime(endmonth + " " + endday + " , " + endyear + " " + endhours +:+ endminute +:+ endsecond);
```

but this doesn't seem to be correct.
Any ideas how I can get a user to enter a date in the correct format easily? I thought select drop-downs might be easiest?

Comment: if you don't mind: http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you targeting modern browsers? If so, you can use the `date` input type:

```
<input type="date">
```

Comment: Hi Bernhard - your answer seems to work and was the easiest to implement. Thanks

Comment: actually using type="datetime" worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

The `setTime()` function expects a timestamp as input (milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00), not a string.

Better to use a library like [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) as suggested by bitsMix in the comments.

Comment: Is it possible to use momentjs with dropdown selects? I dont see any info on something like that on their page - sorry, I am kinda new to JS.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
var d = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

Comment: Hi AlexS
I get an invalid date error when following your suggestion.
Any other ideas?
Do you need any more information from me?

Comment: Take a look http://jsfiddle.net/9RGTx/1/ Can you modify the sample to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: I can see few problems. 1. 'var mili = "00;"' - Syntax error. should be 'var mili = "00";' 2. You pass parameters to Date constructor in wrong order. Year should be 1st, Month - 2nd, Day - 3rd. In your code - month is first. Hope this helps.